# How can you retrieve "Other Names" records from SOAP API

Tags: netsuite

Title says it all, I'm having trouble finding the right SOAP requests to get a list of the "Other Names" records from the SOAP api. For instance, there's a search request to get OtherNameCategories, but that's not one I see for OtherNames.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "you can't do that": the Other Name record type is not accessible via SuiteTalk: https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2021_2/schema/record/othernamecategory.html

Always check the schema browser (for SuiteTalk) or the records browser (for SuiteScript) for these sorts of things.

Comment: So, I spent quick a long time looking into this, but I guess I'm just shocked there's a record type you can't get access to at all through the API.

Comment: @PatrickWhite, there are several, sadly.